# page element sliding

Tags: css, wordpress

My URL:  [love splash panic](http://ilovesplashpanic.com/)

I added a "Free Shipping on orders over $50" to my header. How can I get this element to not slide left and right when zooming?

The CSS I'm using: `.shipping {position:relative; top:100px; right:-1000px;}`

Comment: Just realized that, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: And chrome and firefox both have that element sliding with zoom in/out

Comment: Tried to check it out, but your site has a crazy loading time (currently >2.5 min and still going) + plenty of 404 resources. Might want to fix those first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `<a>` element inside of the following divs (immediate childs of the `body`): `body > #header-wrapper > #header.container > .margin.clearfix > a.shipping`

After doing this, change the styles as follows:

```
#header .shipping {
     position: absolute;
     right: 83px;
     top: -35px;
}
```

The reason the anchor was moving was because it was relative to its position to the left edge of the screen, causing it to stay towards the left side when zooming out. After doing this, it will instead be relative to the `#header` div, which is centered, and stays that way when zooming out.